# Optimize Prolog solver for 5x5 Peg solitaire game

Tags: prolog

I am trying to find a sequence of steps from the starting board below to a solved state.

```
[[x,x,x,x,x],
 [x,x,x,x,x],
 [x,x,o,x,x],
 [x,x,x,x,x],
 [x,x,x,x,x]]
```

However, it takes a very long time. I have left my program running for 5 hours and have still not found a solution. Is there any way I can optimize this?

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

rotate_clock(Xss, Zss) :-
    transpose(Xss, Yss),
    maplist(reverse, Yss, Zss).

rotate_anti(Xss, Zss) :-
    maplist(reverse, Xss, Yss),
    transpose(Yss, Zss).

linjmp([x, x, o | T], [o, o, x | T]).
linjmp([o, x, x | T], [x, o, o | T]).
linjmp([H|T1], [H|T2]) :- linjmp(T1,T2).

horizjmp([A|T],[B|T]) :- linjmp(A,B).
horizjmp([H|T1],[H|T2]) :- horizjmp(T1,T2).

jump(B,A) :- horizjmp(B,A).
jump(B,A) :- rotate_clock(B,BR), horizjmp(BR,BRJ), rotate_anti(BRJ, A).

num_x(A, C) :- count(A, x, C).

count([],X,0).
count([X|T],X,Y):- count(T,X,Z), Y is 1+Z.
count([H|T],X,Z):- dif(H, X), count(T,X,Z).

sum_list([], 0).
sum_list([H|T], Sum) :-
    sum_list(T, Rest),
    Sum is H + Rest.

solved(A) :-
    maplist(num_x, A, B),
    sum_list(B, C),
    C == 1.

jumps([B1, B2 | []]) :-
    jump(B1, B2),
    solved(B2).
jumps([B1, B2 | Bs]) :-
    jump(B1, B2),
    jumps([B2 | Bs]).

?- jumps([[[x,x,x,x,x], [x,x,x,x,x], [x,x,o,x,x], [x,x,x,x,x], [x,x,x,x,x]]|X]), write(X), !.
```

Comment: Are you sure there are solutions? Unless my solver is buggy and the solution is ending with just one peg in the central position then there are no solutions even adding diagonal moves.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a solution.

Comment: It's been long since I last touched prolog, so I wrote the solver in python first and then in C++ (solving the classical 33-places board is somewhat demanding). You can find my solver here https://github.com/6502/peg-solitaire. It uses a single number to represent a position  (one bit per place, with 0=hole, 1=peg) and a bit array for the map of all visited states (indexed by position number).

Answer (score 0):

Nice puzzle, 2 dimensional constraints are worth to try, even if I think, from [what I read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peg_solitaire), there could be no solution...

Your code is a rather naive brute force solver. Calling transpose/2 (twice!) at every search tree node just to test a vertical pattern sounds overkill.

I'll show my attempt, starting from 'symbolic processing' (and brute force, like yours :) to model the problem.

```
solve_brute_force(S) :-
    build(at(3,3,o),x,I),
    /* uncomment to test...
    I=[[x,x,x,x,x],
       [x,x,x,x,x],
       [x,x,o,x,x],
       [x,x,x,x,x],
       [x,x,x,x,x]],
    */
    % try all...
    % between(1,5,P),between(1,5,Q),build(at(P,Q,x),o,F),
    % or just a specific pattern
    build(at(2,4,x),o,F),
    steps(I,F,S).

steps(F,F,[F]).
steps(A,F,[A|R]) :-
    step(A,B), %show(B),
    steps(B,F,R).

step(A,B) :-
    append(L,[R|Rs],A),
    hmove(R,U),
    append(L,[U|Rs],B).
step(A,B) :-
    append(L,[U0,V0,Z0|Rs],A),
    vmove(U0,V0,Z0, U2,V2,Z2),
    append(L,[U2,V2,Z2|Rs],B).

hmove(R,U) :-
    append(Rl,[x,x,o|Rr],R),
    append(Rl,[o,o,x|Rr],U).
hmove(R,U) :-
    append(Rl,[o,x,x|Rr],R),
    append(Rl,[x,o,o|Rr],U).

vmove(U0,V0,Z0, U2,V2,Z2) :-
    nth0(C,U0,x,U1),nth0(C,V0,x,V1),nth0(C,Z0,o,Z1),!,
    nth0(C,U2,o,U1),nth0(C,V2,o,V1),nth0(C,Z2,x,Z1).
vmove(U0,V0,Z0, U2,V2,Z2) :-
    nth0(C,U0,o,U1),nth0(C,V0,x,V1),nth0(C,Z0,x,Z1),!,
    nth0(C,U2,x,U1),nth0(C,V2,o,V1),nth0(C,Z2,o,Z1).

/*
at_least_2([R|Rs],C,S) :-
    aggregate_all(count,member(S,R),T),
    U is C+T,
    ( U >= 2 -> true ; at_least_2(Rs,U,S) ).

count(B,S,N) :-
    aggregate_all(sum(Xs),
              (member(R,B), aggregate_all(count, member(S,R), Xs)),
              N).
*/

build(Cx,Cy,at(X,Y,A),B,P) :-
    findall(Rs,(between(1,Cy,R),
                findall(S,(between(1,Cx,C),
                          (R=Y,C=X -> S=A ; S=B)), Rs)), P).
build(A_at,B,P) :-
    build(5,5,A_at,B,P).
```

Sorry, it doesn't terminate... but it gives us a small set of tools we can use to better understand the problem.

Did you noticed that every step there will be a peg less ?
Then, we can avoid counting pegs, and this is my better hint for optimization so far.

```
solve(S,R) :-
    build(at(3,3,o),x,I),
    steps_c(I,24,R,S).

steps_c(F,N,N,[F]).
steps_c(A,C,N,[A|R]) :-
    step(A,B), % to debug... show(B),
    succ(D,C), % or D is C-1,
    steps_c(B,D,N,R).
```

Alas, it will not help too much: now we can choice the 'solution' level:

```
 ?- time(solve(S,3)),maplist([T]>>(maplist(writeln,T),nl),S).
% 155,322 inferences, 0.110 CPU in 0.111 seconds (99% CPU, 1411851 Lips)
[x,x,x,x,x]
[x,x,x,x,x]
[x,x,o,x,x]
[x,x,x,x,x]
[x,x,x,x,x]

[x,x,x,x,x]
[x,x,x,x,x]
[o,o,x,x,x]
[x,x,x,x,x]
[x,x,x,x,x]

...
```

Let's evaluate some solutions with 3 poles left:

```
 ?- time(call_nth(solve(S,3),1000)).
% 4,826,178 inferences, 2.913 CPU in 2.914 seconds (100% CPU, 1656701 Lips)
S = [[[x, x, x, x, x], ....

 ?- time(call_nth(solve(S,3),10000)).
% 53,375,354 inferences, 31.968 CPU in 31.980 seconds (100% CPU, 1669646 Lips)
S = [[[x, x, x, x, x],
```

We have about 5K inferences / solution at level 3. But it's clear there are a lot of them. So, it's hopeless to attempt ?- solve(S, 1). This brute force approach doesn't work...

Maybe I will try using better problem domain encoding, and modelling with library(clpfd).